# Can I copy large files faster without using the file cache?

Tags: kernel, cache, memory-usage

After adding the `preload` package, my applications seem to speed up but if I copy a large file, the file cache grows by more than double the size of the file.

By transferring a single 3-4 GB virtualbox image or video file to an external drive, this huge cache seems to remove all the preloaded applications from memory, leading to increased load times and general performance drops.

Is there a way to copy large, multi-gigabyte files **without** caching them (i.e. bypassing  the file cache)? Or a way to whitelist or blacklist specific folders from being cached?

Comment: Make sure you're not suffering from too high write buffering. Try `echo 50000000 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_bytes` and `echo 200000000 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_bytes`. For more details, see https://lonesysadmin.net/2013/12/22/better-linux-disk-caching-performance-vm-dirty_ratio/ for details.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is the [`nocache`](https://github.com/Feh/nocache) utility, which can prepended to a command like `ionice` and `nice`. It works by preloading a library which adds `posix_fadvise` with the `POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED` flag to any open calls.

In simple terms, it *advises* the kernel that caching is not needed for that particular file; the kernel will then *normally* not cache the file. See [here](http://insights.oetiker.ch/linux/fadvise.html) for the technical details.

It does wonders for any huge copy jobs, e. g. if you want to backup a multi terabyte disk in the background with the least possible impact on you running system, you can do something along `nice -n19 ionice -c3 nocache cp -a /vol /vol2`.

A package will be available in Ubuntu 13.10 and up. If you are on a previous release you can either install the [13.10 package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nocache) or opt for [this 12.04  backport](https://launchpad.net/~fmarier/+archive/ppa/+index?field.series_filter=precise&batch=75&memo=75&start=75) by François Marier.

Comment: I was hoping for something that could be done via the GUI, as well as a way to simply blacklist the 'no cache' folders, but this will have to do for now.

Answer (score 15):

#### For single large files, use `dd` with *direct* I/O to bypass the file cache:

If you want to transfer one (or a few) large multi-gigabyte files, it's easy to do with `dd`:

```
dd if=/path/to/source of=/path/to/destination bs=4M iflag=direct oflag=direct
```

- The `direct` flags tell `dd` to use the kernel's direct I/O option (`O_DIRECT`) while reading and writing, thus completely bypassing the file cache.
- The `bs` blocksize option must be set to a reasonably large value since to minimize the number of physical disk operations `dd` must perform, since reads/writes are no longer cached and too many small direct operations can result in a serious slowdown.

  - Feel free to experiment with values from 1 to 32 MB; the setting above is 4 MB (`4M`).

**For multiple/recursive directory copies**, unfortunately, there are no easily available tools; the usual `cp`,etc *do not* support direct I/O.

/e iflags & oflags changed to the correct iflag & oflag

Comment: Recursive could be done with `zsh`'s `**` operator. `zsh` needs to be installed manually from the repos.

Comment: Actually, no. `dd`'s weird syntax fouls up the ** oprtator. You could still use a shell script that got arguments normally(`dd.sh in.file out.file` with ** in the filenames) and gave the filenames to `dd` using `$1`, `$2`, etc, which should not be fouled by dd's weird syntax.

Comment: Direct makes is very slow, since it AFAIK also disables the readahead caches, which is probably not what you want, and is not realistic in a benchmarking scenario either. Use "iflag=nocache oflag=nocache" instead, which exactly says to the OS that you don't need the in-file or the out-file cached.

Answer (score 2):

## You can copy a directory recursively with `dd` using `find` and `mkdir`

**We need to workaround two problems:**

1. `dd` doesn't know what to do with directories
2. `dd` can only copy one file at a time

First let's define input and output directories:

```
SOURCE="/media/source-dir"
TARGET="/media/target-dir"
```

Now let's `cd` into the source directory so `find` will report relative directories we can easily manipulate:

```
cd "$SOURCE"
```

Duplicate the directory tree from `$SOURCE` to `$TARGET`

```
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p "$TARGET{}" \;
```

Duplicate files from `$SOURCE` to `$TARGET` omitting write cache (but utilising read cache!)

```
find . -type f -exec dd if={} of="$TARGET{}" bs=8M oflag=direct \;
```

Please note that this won't preserve file modification times, ownership and other attributes.